# Setup sslh on server with floating ip

Tags: vpn

I was trying to set up [streisand](https://github.com/StreisandEffect/streisand) on DigitalOcean droplet with a floating ip pointing to it because the main ip of the droplet is blocked in my country. The problem is in `sslh` service. `sslh` config contains `listen` param where `host` usually points to the actual ip address of the server. `sslh` listens to all traffic on that host, resolves the protocol and routes it to corresponding ports on `localhost`. `nginx` and other services like `openvpn` bind to ports on `localhost`.

Now I have two ips: the actual server's ip `ip1` and floating ip on DigitalOcean `ip2` which points to the same server. `sslh` is listening on `ip1`.

As I understand it, when I try to reach `ip2` `sslh` can't get the packets and route them because they actually come to `ip2` and are then forwarded to my server by DigitalOcean's machinery while `sslh` is listening on `ip1`. I've tried setting `sslh` to listen to `ip2` which didn't work. Requests to `ip1` work fine (I used another server not in my country to test).

I probably lack knowledge of lower-level networking and how floating ips work. I guess I can somehow modify all incoming packets so that they contain meta info about `ip1` but I think that would break `https`. So the question is: how can I set `sslh` to route traffic that comes from floating ip?